# Working with dates: value provided is not ISO format - Node.js and moment.js

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to transform string from req.query to new Date() object and use it in mongo.db aggregation $gte and $lt (classic search by date range). In the base I store date as Date (format yyyy-mm-dd -> example: manufacturingDate: *2022-06-06T07:00:00.000+00:00*)

The problem is, that I am getting in my console and error: *Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged.*

My api - backend code is:
*The isValid() function I did because, sometimes I choose only startDate and then it gives me Invalid date for endDate*

```
    router.get("/searchDate", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        function isValid(data: any) {
          if (data == "Invalid Date") {
            return new Date(moment("2100-11-11"));
          } else {
            return data;
          }
        }
    
        const { startDate, endDate } = req.query;
    
    
        const containers = await Container.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [
                {
                  manufacturingDate: {
                    $gte: isValid(new Date(moment(startDate))),
                    $lt: isValid(new Date(moment(endDate))),
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        ]);


    res.status(200).json(containers);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: "Container not found" });
  }
});
```

In the req.query I pass the date in format (yyyy-mm-dd), example: 2022-06-06, BUT if I chose only FROM, then this problem occurs because I send an endDate = undefined to my API.

Code is:

```
onChangeDate() {
   function convert(str: any) {
      var date = new Date(str),
        mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
      return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
    }

 this.containersService
      .getContainersByDateRange(convert(this.from), convert(this.to))
      .subscribe((containers: any) => {
          this.containers = containers;
        
      });

}
```

I know that I can't convert undefined and thats why I than get this error. Is there some workaround trick?

Comment: In your collection, are you storing a BSON date or a string?

Comment: I am storing as type Date. That is how it looks in my collection: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2clEk.png)